# Llevar un historial de cambios en información

Tags: sql-server, asp.net, asp.net-core

Espero me puedan orientar con lo siguiente:
Estoy empezando con ASP.NET Core, la base de datos en Sql Server.

Necesito registrar en un log los cambios que el usuario haga a la información.
Por ej. Si al editar a un cliente de nombre JUAN y se cambia a JUAN PENAS, quiero detectar el cambio e ir guardando esos cambios en una tabla, el texto sería : "El día 11/11/2020 11:11:11 am, el usuario x hizo el cambio de nombre de JUAN a JUAN PENAS" , esto ya lo tengo, detecto el cambio y armo el texto por medio de JavaScript.

Lo que no se es como agregarlo a una tabla que se llama "LOGS".

En mi lógica es que cada cambio mandarlo a agregar (A no se donde, para mi antes era una tabla temporal),
Mientras el usuario sigue modificando datos , igual yo guardándolos en temporal, una vez que el usuario manda a guardar la información, entonces guardar los datos del modelo y luego obtener ese temporal y recorrerlo para ir guardando los cambios que se hicieron
Según mi li lógica es que cada cambio mandarlo por AJAX a ese temporal o a esa colección pero que esa colección este pegada al modelo de clientes como comenté.

He tratado de que al Modelo Clientes agregarle un List o un Collection que apunte a al modelo LOGS y según yo, tener como un apartado dentro del modelo de cliente algo como Clientes.Logs y en este tener los campos que lleva en si el "modelo logs", he intentado de muchas formas pero tal vez por mi falta de dominio de las colecciones o List, no lo he podido hacer, si es que es por ahi la solución.

```
public class Clientes
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public virtual Bitacora Bitacora { get; set; }

        //public List<LOGS> LOGS { get; set; }
        // public virtual ICollection<LOGS> LOGS { get; set; }
   }
```

En el Modelo que pongo, las dos últimas líneas ignoradas porque no se para donde darle , ni como llenarlas.

Agradezco su apoyo y espero haberme explicado.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No es simplemente al guardar algo, hacer un insert en la tabla de logs? me parece que estas complicando algo simple.. es eso, o un trigger en tu db que por cada update o insert guarde la informacion en otra tabla...

Comment: Hola. Por favor sigue las recomendaciones que te dio @gbianchi. Y, cambia el enfoque. Pues tendrás que considerar cualquier acción de teclado que genere cambios como tal, incluidos los `[ctrl + v]` y si adicionalmente piensas enviar vía ajax al servidor vas a generar un tráfico absurdo. Piensa en usar localstorage y hacer envíos a servidor en bloques de tamaño razonable cada n acciones con n suficientemente grande.

Comment: Es mi primera pregunta, disculpen, tomaré en cuenta tu recomendación y si me expandí.

Comment: Quevedo, buscaré información respecto a localstorage, en realidad no pensé en el tráfico al servidor considerando que realmente no hay muchas modificaciones a los datos de clientes, pero si es importante para una empresa, saber quien cuando y que modifico el usuario, muchas veces hablamos de cambios de direcciones, etc.  te agradezco.